# api.get_user with Tweepy will not give description

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to use Tweepy (version 4.4.0) to get a user's description but it's seemingly not working:

```
u = api.get_user(username='XXXX', user_fields=['description'])
```

but the output of this is simply:

```
Response(data=<User id=123 name=XXX username=XXX>, includes={}, errors=[], meta={})
```

So it's getting me the name and id fine, but it's returning an empty for any user fields.

Note I've also tried with user_auth: 1, but I get 'Unauthorized: 401' - but from what I've seen around, I don't think user authentication is the problem here... but maybe it is?

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1):

`api` seems to be an instance of [`tweepy.Client`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.4.0/client.html#tweepy.Client) here.

From [the relevant FAQ section in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.4.0/faq.html#why-am-i-not-getting-expansions-or-fields-data-with-api-v2-using-client):

> Why am I not getting expansions or fields data with API v2 using Client?
>
> If you are simply printing the objects and looking at that output, the string representations of API v2 models/objects only include the default attributes that are guaranteed to exist.
>
> The objects themselves still include the relevant data, which you can access as attributes or by key, like a dictionary.

The user object being returned in the response should have a `description` field with the user's description.

Comment: To be clear, we can use user.data.description in this case.

Comment: No, if `user` is a User object, then `user.data` will be a dictionary with the raw JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the description with: **u.data.description**

Keep in mind that the description may be blank some times, try with created_at to be sure it works.

Comment: It would be great if you could show a small example for how these functions are used.

Answer (score -1):

Sample code for extracting description of any twitter user is as follows

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuth2BearerHandler(os.environ.get("TWITTER_API_KEY"))
api = tweepy.API(auth)
user = api.get_user(screen_name="TechWiser", include_entities=False)
description = user._json['description']
```

`user._json` contain many other key, value pair that you can explore

Comment: Have updated my answer and tested this. It's the working solution

Comment: This only works with the old API 1.1, which new developer accounts cannot use